# Is there a companion to Ext JS Element.addClassOnOver?

Tags: javascript, extjs

In Ext JS, I see Element.addClassOnOver; is there an easy way to "remove class when no longer over?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

addClassOnOver does that for you automatically. Have you tried it?  There's no need to manually remove the over class.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I have tried addClassOnOver (3.3.1), and the classes added are not removed.  Actually, I am using SuperBoxSelect; in enableElListeners, the classes x-superboxselect-item and x-superboxselect-item-hover are never removed.  Maybe it's a bug???

Comment: Sounds like a bug in SBS. The standard addClassOnOver method sets up a remove handler automatically.

Comment: You are correct; bug in SBS.  It calls addClassonOver with two classes separated by a space; all is well when two calls are made.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
var removeFn = function(e){
  if(!e.within(this.el, true)){
    Ext.fly(this, '_internal').removeClass(className);
  }
};

this.on('mouseout', removeFn, this.dom);
```

refer :

[addClassOnOver](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?3302-addClassOnOver)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried handling the mouseout event, without success.  However, I am not familiar with _internal - as a root for the DOM search?  Would you expound?

Comment: @Upper Stage : Ext.fly(String/HTMLElement el, [String named]) accepts 2 params, el : The dom node or id & named : String Allows for creation of named reusable flyweights to prevent conflicts (e.g. internally Ext uses "_global"), you can use Ext.get also. Refer : http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/docs/source/Element.html#method-Ext-fly

Comment: I understand the parameters to fly; I was asking about the string, '_internal'.  What is '_internal'?  (+1 for your help)

Comment: @Upper Stage : SuperBoxSelect; in enableElListeners - add this.el.on('mouseout', function(){this.el.removeClass('x-superboxselect-item-hover');},this);

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried handling the mouseout event, without success

Comment: @Upper Stage : replace enableElListeners function in SuperBoxSelect.js with this :     `enableElListeners : function(){
        this.el.on('click', this.onElClick, this, {stopEvent:true});
  this.el.addClassOnOver('x-superboxselect-item x-superboxselect-item-hover');
  this.el.on('mouseout', function(){this.el.removeClass('x-superboxselect-item-hover');},this);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

In SuperBoxSelect this is a bug it seems.

To fix the SBS bug, I simply changed:

```
this.el.addClassOnOver('x-superboxselect-item x-superboxselect-item-hover');
```

to:

```
this.el.addClassOnOver('x-superboxselect-item-hover');
```

This solves the problem very nicely, with no side effects that i could see.